# Circle won't display on screen: TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not float

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, geometry

I am trying to make a circle and a rectangle appear on my screen. The rectangle seems to work, but the circle doesn't. When ever I run this code the error is the same:

```
TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not float
```

Code:

```
#Game.py
survivor.draw(screen)
Zombie.draw_zombies(screen)
```

and so this loops back to:

```
class Zombie(Character):

    List = []

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        Character.__init__(self, x, y)
        Zombie.List.append(self)

    @staticmethod
    def draw_zombies(screen):
        for zombie in Zombie.List:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, [210, 24, 77], zombie)


class Survivor(Character):

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        Character.__init__(self, x, y)

    def draw(self, screen):
        r = self.width / 2
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, [77, 234, 156], (self.x + r), (self.y + r), r)
```

and so when I run this i always get the same thing:

```
TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not float
```

and I have all the imports and everything, suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula I believe you need:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (77, 234, 156), (int(self.x + r),int(self.y + r)), int(r))
```

if you are still having issues, do the "+" operational into a local var, then int that var.